# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] intermittently returning two leading forward slashes

Tags: php

Why would $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] return a filename in one instance as /test/foo.bar and another instance (executed from the same php script) as //test/foo.bar (with double leading forward slashes)?

form.php sends $_GET to login.php. login.php redirects to

```
header ('Location: test/foo.bar')
```

foo.bar includes:

```
$page = filter_var($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

(*Additionally, I cannot replicate it on demand.* )

Comment: Can you show some code? It's very unlikely for the variable to change by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you're building links in code somewhere (or maybe someone just typed in an extra slash somewhere).  You might have some code along these lines:

```
function buildLink($site, $relPath, $text) {
    return "<a href=\"$site/$relPath\">$text</a>";
}
```

If `$site` is passed in with a trailing slash in some cases, you'd end up with the leading double slash when the server name was removed.  Or if an absolute path was passed in.  An extra slash won't affect which page is displayed, but it would still show up in the parsed url.

Comment: Scouring for the extra slash now. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` depends on the actual request sent by the client. Apache allows multiple slashes between directory names, so it treats `http://example/foo.php` the same as `http://example//foo.php` -- both will call `foo.php` but the request URI will contain whatever the client requested.

If your script expects only one slash, you will have to manually strip the remaining.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why the same browser on the same client computer would request the same file with one then two leading slashes?

Comment: @tgrass - Look at the links they followed to get there.  Dumping the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` along with the PHP_SELF may help find you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].  Take note that PHP_SELF is vulnerable to a few types of attack, so be careful when using it.  You have to treat it as if it was user supplied input.

Comment: Replaced with SCRIPT_NAME and it still returns the two leading slashes.

Comment: we'll need to see more code.  there is something else at play here